# Export compiler flags for all the targets in modern CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm porting one project to modern CMake. The project has a compiler flag that must be set and exported for all the targets. To avoid repeating `target_compile_option` for all the targets I tried with `add_compile_options`, but the latter seems to not export the flag so that it is not used by downstream targets linking the upstream libraries of my project. So do I really have to call `target_compile_option` for all my targets or is there a workaround?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What kind of a compiler option and what kind of a project you are talking about? It could be you project has a single "base" target and you link this target into every other target. That way, specifying option with `target_compile_option` for the base target, you ensure all other targets to use it.

Comment: It is a preprocessor flag, used in almost all the sources of my libraries to guard the usage of code from an optional library. I have not a common target linked by all my targets, so I cannot use your workaround.

Comment: Are those libs always part of the same project or do they need to work individually too?

Comment: @fabian They are part of the same project, but downstream doesn't necessarily need to link all of them. They provide different functionalities which (to a certain degree) are not correlated, so a downstream can link just the needed ones.

Answer (score 0):

Since the libs are always part of the same project you can define a macro in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` and use this macro instead of `add_library`. This way you can add common logic inside the macro in addition to `add_library`:

```
macro(my_add_library TARGET_NAME)
    add_library(${TARGET_NAME} ${ARGN})
    target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE -myOption)
endmacro()

...
my_add_library(mylib1 SHARED foo.cpp bar.cpp)

...
my_add_library(mylib2 STATIC util.cpp)
```

Note that the `my_add_library` command is also available in subdirectories you add after defining the macro so you should be able to use it for all the libraries.

Comment: This indeed would work, thanks. Does this also mean that there is no "native modern CMake" way to do so? If yes, is this because it is considered bad practice or just a missing feature?